# Dax code in Power BI for getting specific column

Tags: powerbi, dax, var, summarize

I need to get specific column which rows are depended on another column. Here is the raw example table,

| Affiliate | Brand |
| --- | --- |
| x17 | B |
| x17 | B |
| x17 | B |
| x17 | B |
| x17 | B |
| x17 | B |
| 1x2 | B |
| 1x2 | F |
| 1x2 | F |
| 1x2 | B |
| 1x2 | F |
| 1x2 | B |
| 1x2 | F |
| 1x2 | B |
| 1x2 | F |
| 1x2 | B |
| 1x2 | F |
| 1x2 | B |
| x456 | B |
| x456 | B |
| x456 | B |
| x456 | B |
| x456 | B |
| x456 | B |
| x456 | B |
| x456 | B |
| x456 | B |

I need a measure that gives the affiliate's names according to the number of different brands they are in.

For example;

**x17** affiliate is included in only **"B"** brand, so it will be shown only 1 row.

**1x2** affiliate is included in both **"B"** and **"F"** brands, so it will be shown 2 rows.

| Required Column as measure |
| --- |
| x17 |
| 1x2 |
| 1x2 |
| x456 |

Comment: Your expected results are not currently clear.

Comment: I've tried to explain it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Use this which returns a table of required column:

```
Table = SELECTCOLUMNS(DISTINCT('Table'), "Affiliate", 'Table'[Affiliate])
```

Answer (score 0):

Measures don't return tables/columns.

If you are meaning or wanting to create a **Calculated Table** then you could try something similar to:

```
My New Table =
  SELECTCOLUMNS(
    SUMMARIZE('YourTable', [Affiliate], [Brand]),
    "Affiliate", [Affiliate]
  )
```